# How do I check for Google Play Services API availability? (specifically the GCM API)

Tags: android, api, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am trying to use GCM to do async communication between my app and a tiny backend Java server running on my personal computer. My problem is I can't figure out the cross-linked and contradictory reference pages for GCM and Google Play Services. I would love to use one of the old answers to this question, but the API and documentation got reworked in the last couple months and all the similar questions I find are from last year or older.

[Google's guide for setting up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Setup) says to ensure the required APIs are present using either:

1. The GoogleApiClient class, which provides an example for using the Drive API (`.addApi(Drive.API)`), but there is no `GoogleCloudMessaging.API` that I can find, so that's not going to work.
2. "Another approach is to use the [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) method." This links to the GooglePlayServicesUtil class, but nearly every method in this class is deprecated in favor of GoogleApiAvailability's non-static version, and I would understandably like to avoid using deprecated code wherever possible. The GoogleApiAvailability class also won't let me instantiate it.

So my questions are these: How can I ensure that a device has an updated version of Google Play Services? And is there a way to check whether the GCM API is available before I use it (or do I even need to do this if Google Play Services is updated)?

Additional info:

Min SDK 14

Target SDK 22

Apologies for not linking to some of the docs, darn reputation link limits.

Comment: Did you try using `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()`?

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @GabeV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Nugent for pointing out that I had missed the existence of `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()`!